# Unable to install software by using WineHQ Stable

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bash, wine

I've installed wine 6.0.1 today (by following these steps: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-desktop/) to install MetaTrader 5 software. I'm getting the following errors in the installation process:

```
cxxxxxxxxxx@chinmay-OL-RACK-001:~/Downloads$ wine ./mt5setup.exe 
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0100:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0100:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f8:fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity 0000000000000000, -1, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 0, 3, 0000000000000000, 0, 0000000000000000 stub
00f8:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 000000000125FD50, 000000000006A8E0, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, 0000000000000000, 0x00000000
00f8:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 000000000125FD50
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  0 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  222
  Current serial number in output stream:  222
```

My desktop's configuration:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64
CPU: Intel i5 760 (4) @ 2.801GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series
Memory: 2611MiB / 15975MiB
Kernel: 5.11.0-27-generic
Shell: bash 5.0.17
```

Comment: Of course you have already checked https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1081 to see if the app is supported on wine and any restrictions.

Comment: to @David - I am already using MetaTrader 5 in Elementary OS 5.1 Hera (based on Ubuntu 18.04) on my other PC. It's working fine with Wine 6.0.

Comment: That is not a supported version here it is NOT Ubuntu

Comment: Are you talking about Elementary OS or MetaTrader 5 software? I don't think the Elementary OS has any magic chain to run this application. Because it totally depends upon Ubuntu! @David

Comment: Elementary OS the OS.

Comment: I'm just sharing that it's working fine on Elementary OS (based on Ubuntu). But, this software isn't working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Is there any solution? Kindly help.